# How to open Material-UI Dialog from parent component - React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog

I know there are a few questions like this on stack overflow already but I have been trying to use their answers and had no success; so I am posting my code on here as it was before I tried the solutions that did not work. I have been able to open a modal from parent component using ant-design before using similar method but having trouble with Material-UI.

I have imported my modal (material-ui dialog) into my parent card component where I already have an info icon button that I want to use to open the modal (material-ui dialog). I don't get any errors however it does not work, code is below.

Modal.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import MuiDialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import MuiDialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import MuiDialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    margin: 0,
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  closeButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: theme.spacing(1),
    top: theme.spacing(1),
    color: theme.palette.grey[500],
  },
});

const DialogTitle = withStyles(styles)((props) => {
  const { children, classes, onClose, ...other } = props;
  return (
    <MuiDialogTitle disableTypography className={classes.root} {...other}>
      <Typography variant="h6">{children}</Typography>
      {onClose ? (
        <IconButton aria-label="close" className={classes.closeButton} onClick={onClose}>
          <CloseIcon />
        </IconButton>
      ) : null}
    </MuiDialogTitle>
  );
});

const DialogContent = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}))(MuiDialogContent);

const DialogActions = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    margin: 0,
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}))(MuiDialogActions);

export default function () {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title" open={open}>
        <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
          Modal title
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent dividers>
          <Typography gutterBottom>
            Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis
            in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom>
            Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis
            lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom>
            Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel
            scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus
            auctor fringilla.
          </Typography>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button autoFocus onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Save changes
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Card.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import AddShoppingCartIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddShoppingCart';
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Info';
import MaterialModal from './Modal';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
    ["@media (max-width: 376px)"]: {
      maxWidth: 275,
    },
    ["@media (max-width: 321px)"]: {
      maxWidth: 250,
    }
    
    
  },
  media: {
    height: 140,
    maxHeight: 140,
  },
  button: {
    paddingLeft: "8rem",
    paddingBottom: "1rem"
  },
  button1: {
    paddingLeft: "4rem",
    paddingBottom: "1rem"
  }
});

export default function MediaCard(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image={props.image}
          title={props.title}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {props.header}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            {props.price}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button className={classes.button1}  size="small" color="primary">
          <AddShoppingCartIcon/>
        </Button>
        <Button className={classes.button} size="small" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
          <InfoIcon/>
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
      <MaterialModal open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"/>
    </Card>
    
  );
}
```

Comment: Remove the state from the modal and pass the `open`, `handleClose` to the modal component. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-gdpj3?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Thanks Medi that works! Just having issues getting the modal to close now hanldeClose does not seem to be working

Comment: I updated the answer [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-gdpj3?file=/src/index.js). Change the prop name from `onClose` to `handleClose`.

Comment: Worked it out, but you confirmed my fix thanks Medi!